# H2 file embedded mode runscript on creating db(not initializing connection)

Tags: java, sql, url, jdbc, h2

I need to create H2 file db on demand(first connection) from backup-ed script. 
As I understand it could be done only by using two different urls:

- jdbc:h2:file:sampledb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'create.sql'; (Should be executed only one time)
- jdbc:h2:file:sampledb;IFEXISTS=TRUE;

The problem is that in application connection to db is coming from JNDI so I should set up only one correct url. Does any ability exist to specify parameters based on some condition?
And how to get this conditionn from H2? (Something like jdbc:h2:file:sampledb;!{dbixists}=runscript...). Or some ternary operation is allowed?

Comment: No.(( Just custom application with ability to connect to any db(specified by user). So the task is to have sample working connection (with provided tutorial data about and for application samples). But this data is not needed for experienced user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply include `IF NOT EXIST` clauses inside the `create.sql` script and run it everytime. It would create the DB model only if there is no proper model at all.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this. But in really I`m not familiar with H2 engine - i doubt thatit can became a bottleneck for performance. As 
for creation is used a big amount of data. So checking existence for every statement is less preferable that check its once per connection.

At least it could be just a workaround. If there are no other variants.